Connection Error [Errno 110] Connection timed out
I have been trying to complete a capture the flag assignment whereby I need to bypass a SSO authentication protocol by using Impacket's getST.py but whenever I try running the getST.py command I end up getting a connection timed out error. How can I fix this problem?
